# Angular ui-select : Change theme

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select

I'm here for a question

What is the best way to change the theme of ui-select input fields, Hack CSS ?
Do you have other leads?

Comment: Sagiliteste, have you considered [selecting an aswer as "Accepted"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select) you can set a theme **for all `ui-select`** in your app by doing this:

```
app.config(function(uiSelectConfig) {
  uiSelectConfig.theme = 'bootstrap';
  //... other config options
});
```

... or **for a specific `ui-select`** with this code:

```
<ui-select theme="bootstrap">
    ...
</ui-select>
```

Available themes are: *bootstrap, select2* and *selectize*

If you want to set a custom *css* rules for any specific element generated by the `ui-select` directive you should create a custom *css* file and override the rules defined in the *ui-select's css* file

Answer (score 0):

[This one](https://github.com/axel-zarate/js-custom-select) better to customize with CSS.